# jQuery Mobile Open individual json object on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a news mobile app and so far I've been able to pull the JSON string and display on my page however I'm not sure how to open each individual news item on a new jquery mobile page.
Here's my code below.

Thanks for your help.

```js
$.getJSON("http://kyivcool.veedoogroup.com/?json=11", function(data){
    $(data.posts)
  $('#cont').append("<div>");
  $(data.posts).each(function(key, post){
  $('#cont').append( "<div class='img-thumb'><a href='#fullText'><img src='" + post.thumbnail+ "'></a></div>" );
  $('#cont').append( "<div class='title-post'><a href='"+ post.url+ "'><h4>" + post.title + "</h4></a></div>" );
  $('#cont').append( "<div class='author-post'>" + post.author.name + "</div>" );
  $('#cont').append( "<div class='excerpt-post'>" + post.excerpt + "</div>" );
  $('#cont').append( "<hr>" );
alert(data.posts[0].title_plain)});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the json array of posts to a global javascript variable. 
Then put the post id in the link as a data-attribute.
Then handle the click event of the links, get the post id, and find the content in the global array. finlly put the content in a DIV in the separate page.

```
var thePosts;
$(document).on("pagecreate","#page1", function(){ 

  $.ajax({ 
      url: 'http://kyivcool.veedoogroup.com/?json=11',
      dataType : 'jsonp',
      success  : function (data) { 
          thePosts = data.posts; //SAVE TO GLOBAL VARIABLE              
          $('#cont').append("<div>");
          $(data.posts).each(function(key, post){
            $('#cont').append( "<div class='img-thumb'><a data-postid='"+ post.id+ "' href='#fullText' class='fullTextLink'><img src='" + post.thumbnail+ "'></a></div>" );
            $('#cont').append( "<div class='title-post'><a href='"+ post.url+ "'><h4>" + post.title + "</h4></a></div>" );
            $('#cont').append( "<div class='author-post'>" + post.author.name + "</div>" );
            $('#cont').append( "<div class='excerpt-post'>" + post.excerpt + "</div>" );
            $('#cont').append( "<hr>" );
          });
      }    
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".fullTextLink", function(){      
    var id = $(this).data("postid");   
    for (var i=0; i<thePosts.length; i++){
        if (thePosts[i].id == id) {
          $("#fullTextDiv").html(thePosts[i].content);
          break;
        }    
    }
  });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9e7vhbma/)